# how to send mail dynamically in business catalyst?

Tags: jquery, email, adobe, business-catalyst

I am working with Adobe business catalyst.
I have created a web form with multiple fields and among them three fields are dynamic from "Web Apps".

There is a field named "Select Location". With every location ,"email address" will be attached with data-value. When user select particular location, a default BC email will be send to the "email address" attached to selected location.

How to perform this task? please help in sorting out this issue.

Comment: no one here to reply to this question? please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like the webform data to be sent to an email address that is taken from a data attribute on a select option within the form being filled.

This article should help. 
https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/user-manual/CRM/web-forms/setting-up-form-to-email-using-web-forms

Essentially you want to append &Email=email@address.com to the form action to achieve your goal.

You could do that with javascript or jquery front end.

jQuery example below

```
var frmAction = $('form[name="catwebformform22094"]').attr('action')
$('form :input').change(function () {
$(this).closest('form').data('changed', true);
var selectedEmail = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).attr(' data-email');
$('form[name="catwebformform22094"]').attr('action', frmAction + "&Email=" + selectedEmail)
})
```

Comment: Perfect.
I will surely give a try.
 Solution is better then ever, i think so.

Comment: Much better than my answer. I will definitely use this one.

Comment: Just a note, this functionality has now been deprecated.
  https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2425172#

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

You can create a whole new form, hide it and set that form to send emails on submit, and submit it when the first form is submitted. 
Then pass  the email value as below.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataLoc = $('select.location').attr('data-value-email');
        $('form.hidden input.email').val() = dataLoc;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: in this case i have to do some core coding, right? But in BC , we can't do server side scripting.

Comment: btw i have found two possible solution. one is using SOAP API and other is using third party.

Comment: You don't need any coding more than html and jquery. You just create a form with only one field called email, and set the input field value to the email which you need to send an email to with jQuery. There is almost no coding at all, but there are a lot of things to adjust. If you don't know what I mean it is better to try third party.